# MacOS Sierra, app is running but has no window

Tags: mac, macos

I had an app called "Gitbox" on my Mac for 4 years with no problems. **App suddenly does not display it's main window** when running. The little dot is under the app in dock. I cannot delete the app when the dot is there, cause OS says it's running.  I can verify the app is running, because the "Activity" window shows that it's fetching something.

I tried reinstalling, and looking at other "Windows" or desktops, but nothing. Did I use some launch option or hotkey to launch the app in a wrong mode?

Tried:

- Rebooting Mac
- Reinstalling App from the app store
- Dragging and
  restoring to Trash

[image]

[image]

Comment: and the name of the App is......

Comment: The name is Gitbox, it's a source control tool

Comment: hmm last update 5.5 years ago. Already tried to (re)move the prefs file?

Comment: In Script Editor, with Gitbox running, what's the output of this command: `tell application "System Events" to get properties of window 1 of application process "Gitbox"`

Comment: System Events got an error: Can’t get window 1 of application process "Gitbox". Invalid index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleting the preferences here has resolved the problem. Not sure why they did not show up in finder, I think it shows hidden files for me. So I had to use an external tool which actually found hte preference file:

[image]